# not able to mine transactions generated on remote node

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, mining, private-blockchain

i have connected two nodes locally on my private testnet using admin.addPeer()

```
I0829 16:33:25.280649 eth/downloader/downloader.go:320] Block synchronisation started
I0829 16:33:27.187839 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ig
nored) including 1 txs in 5.0005ms. #1 [5992ca33 / 5992ca33]
I0829 16:33:27.194840 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ig
nored) including 0 txs in 4.0004ms. #2 [a7d03425 / a7d03425]
I0829 16:33:27.201841 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ig
nored) including 0 txs in 4.0004ms. #3 [c830dc48 / c830dc48]
I0829 16:38:10.295147 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ig
nored) including 1 txs in 7.0007ms. #4 [0b5dda9b / 0b5dda9b]

I0829 16:41:26.715787 eth/api.go:1193] Tx(0x8dc736b5ad28770506e917d0edba187fa0cb
e2e62c1e71129f061e2789731f82) to: 0xfb02474300b1dc625a6cc19cc10e7ac963183695
"0x8dc736b5ad28770506e917d0edba187fa0cbe2e62c1e71129f061e2789731f82"

> I0829 16:41:56.317747 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0
ignored) including 0 txs in 5.0005ms. #7 [9744d1d6 / 9744d1d6]
I0829 16:41:58.201936 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ig
nored) including 0 txs in 5.0005ms. #8 [81d0a6a4 / 81d0a6a4]
I0829 16:42:01.574273 core/blockchain.go:964] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ig
nored) including 0 txs in 5.0005ms. #9 [19fd5783 / 19fd5783]

> eth.pendingTransactions
[{
blockHash: null,
blockNumber: null,
from: "0x076dba93600dbbc8928b02af47b14465a4274b62",
gas: 90000,
gasPrice: 20465684346,
hash: "0x8dc736b5ad28770506e917d0edba187fa0cbe2e62c1e71129f061e2789731f82",
input: "0xd7bb99ba",
nonce: 0,
to: "0xfb02474300b1dc625a6cc19cc10e7ac963183695",
transactionIndex: null,
value: 300
}]
```

the two have synchronised well. yet when i try to mine on first node the transaction generated on node 2 then the transaction is always in the pending mode. the transaction does not get mined. what should be done to avoid this?

Comment: What does `eth.pendingTransactions` give you on mining node?

Comment: do the sync on the nodes *eth.syncing*